# Sightly: check for empty lists

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly

Using `data-sly-list` I can iterate over a list object in Sightly, but how can I check if a list is empty? `data-sly-list` simply renders nothing on empty list objects and I need to display an alternativ text if the list contains no items.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `data-sly-test` and `!` operator:

```
<div data-sly-test="${!myList}">List is empty</div>
```

Comment: Can you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761951/sightly-empty-check-on-list-htl?